# Using custom fields in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new to wordpress and I tried to set up a custom post types for my blog using custom fields.

To do so, I used the Custom Post Types UI plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/
I created a new type "Movies" which supports custom fields. I have added a custom field named 'Release Date' in my post but I can't find a way to print it.

I display my posts using the following code:

```
  <ul>

  <?php
  $args = array( 'post_type' => 'movies', 'posts_per_page' => 3 );
  $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
  ?>
  <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { ?>
  <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { $the_query->the_post(); ?>

    <li class="news-item">
        <h3><?php the_title()?></h3>
        <h6><?php the_field('release_date')?></h6>
        <p><?php the_content()?></p>
    </li>
          <?php
      }
    }
    else {
      echo 'no movies here!';
    }
  ?>

  </ul>
```

But nothing gets printed. However if I removed the `<h6><?php the_field('release_date')?></h6>` everything else works just fine.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Maybe you miss a `;` in `the_field('release_date')` -> `<h6><?php the_field('release_date');?></h6>`. Wherever, i recommend us ACF Plugin, its better than Custom Field UI: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/

Comment: `the_field()` is a function of Advanced Custom Fields (http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/). Have you installed that plugin?

Comment: oh ok, I didnt know that. How can I display a custom field using only Custom Post Types UI?

Comment: Try `echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'release_date', true );` Read more about it here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta - Whenever you can, always use core functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check here [how to get post meta field](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta). you can use something like this

```
 <?php 
    $key_1_value = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'release_date', true );
    // check if the custom field has a value
    if( ! empty( $key_1_value ) ) {
      echo $key_1_value;
    } else
   {

   echo "release date not present ";
   }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: (Assuming you are not using ACF plugin.)

```
$release_date = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'release_date', true);
if( $release_date ) {
    echo $release_date;
} else {
    echo "Error getting release date";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To better development i suggest to use Advance custom field plugins